# PHP MongoDB update multiple documents using $in/$or

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm having trouble figuring out how to construct an update query in PHP that will update document IDs X,Y, and Z. Does anyone have experience with this?

```
$ids[] = array(
  new MongoId('4eaaf929498fe2c80300000c'),
  new MongoId('4eaaff24498fe2ba0900001f')
); 
$collection->update(
  array('_id' => array('$in' => $ids)),
  array('$set' => array("title"=>"test")),
  array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Comment: Update document IDs or update based on document IDs? If the latter, update what exactly? Can you show some code?

Comment: So I want to update the field "title" on document IDs X,Y and Z.

Here is my current code:

$ids[] = array(new MongoId('4eaaf929498fe2c80300000c'), new MongoId('4eaaff24498fe2ba0900001f'));
$collection->update(array('_id' => array('$in' => $ids)), array('$set' => array("title"=>"test")), array("upsert" => true));

Answer (score 10):

I assume that your trouble is, that only one document get's updated, right? If this is the case, there is another setting you have to specifiy in the third parameter (the options parameter) for the update method:

```
multiple => true
```

Otherwise, it will only update the first match of your query. See the documentation to the update method at:

http://de.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

Comment: Yes, the PHP Driver is using a different parameter name. In mongo default api, the option is called only `multi`