# Multi update with $set and php Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, mlab, nosql

I'm trying to update multiple items in a collection using the update() function with multi=true param on mongolab platform. **The problem is only the first item in the collection is updated**.

The collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5454b446e4b02a012c939a0a"
    },
    "value": "1234",
    "name": "first"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5454b446e4b02a012c939a0a"
    },
   "value": "1234",
   "name": "second"
}
```

Script code:

```
$db->collection->update(
    array('value' => '1234'),
    array('$set' => array(
        'name' => 'example name',
    )),
    array('multi' => true)
);
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5454b446e4b02a012c939a0a"
    },
    "value": "1234",
    "name": "example name"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5454b446e4b02a012c939a0a"
    },
   "value": "1234",
   "name": "second"
}
```

The update() function accepts only three arrays as arguments.

Comment: the manual is your friend. check the correct syntax.

Comment: Solved with "multiple" => "true" instead of "multi".

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934119/php-mongodb-update-multiple-documents-using-in-or

Comment: @Hadokee, please add that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Yogesh,
I think your query should be:

```
db.collectionName.update({"value":"1234"},{$set:{"name":"example name"}},{'upsert':true, 'multiple': true});
```

The corresponding PHP codes would be:

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient(); //connects to local mongo

    $db_name = 'ri'; //replace database name you want to work with
    $collection_name = 'brand_graph'; //replace collection name you want to work with

    $select = $m->selectDB($db_name)->selectCollection($collection_name);

    $where_array = array(
        'value' => 1234
    );

    $update_data = array(
        '$set' => array(
            'name' => 'example name'
        )
    );

    $options = array(
        'upsert' => true,
        'multiple' => true
    );


    $select->update($where_array, $update_data, $options);
?>
```

I hope this is what your were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I write below mongo query which update multiple documents but , I don't know how to convert this in PHP code but for reference you should use this query

```
 db.collectionName.update({"value":"1234"},{$set:{"name":"example name"}},true,true)
```